# Calling a Web API from another Web API project

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I got three Web API project.

They deployed at

1. api:http://api.domain.com
2. mobileApi:http://mobile.api.domain.com
3. logApi:http://log.api.domain.com

I want do this:
When an error occured in other project,record the error by calling a controller in logApi.I have read http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

So I write this class for helping send request to a Web API controller

```
public class WebApiRequest
{
    public static T Get<T>(string url, object param = null, object header = null, Func<HttpResponseMessage, T> converter = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = GetClient(header);
        url = UrlHelper.BuildUrl(url, param);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return converter != null ? converter(response) : DefaultConverter<T>(response);
    }

    public static T Post<T>(string url, object param = null, object header = null, Func<HttpResponseMessage, T> converter = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = GetClient(header);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            Tool.AnonymousObjectToDictionary(param).Where(i => i.Value != null).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value.ToString()));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return converter != null ? converter(response) : DefaultConverter<T>(response);
    }

    public static T Put<T>(string url, object param = null, object header = null, Func<HttpResponseMessage, T> converter = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = GetClient(header);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            Tool.AnonymousObjectToDictionary(param).Where(i => i.Value != null).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value.ToString()));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return converter != null ? converter(response) : DefaultConverter<T>(response);
    }

    public static T Delete<T>(string url, object param = null, object header = null, Func<HttpResponseMessage, T> converter = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = GetClient(header);
        url = UrlHelper.BuildUrl(url, param);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.DeleteAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return converter != null ? converter(response) : DefaultConverter<T>(response);
    }

    private static T DefaultConverter<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter> {
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(),
            new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()
        };
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatters).Result;
        return result;
    }

    public static string StringConverter(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    private static HttpClient GetClient(object header)
    {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new DecompressionHandler());
        var headers = Tool.AnonymousObjectToDictionary(header);
        foreach (var h in headers.Where(h=>h.Value!=null)) {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(h.Key, h.Value.ToString());
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

In a test project,It works perfect.

But when I use it in a Web API project,things become very strange.

```
    WebApiRequest.Post<ReturnModel<int>>(logUrl, new {
        Source = "{" + source + "}",
        context.Exception.Message,
        context.Exception.StackTrace,
        ExceptionType = context.Exception.GetType().FullName,
        PriorityLevel = 3,
        AddTime = DateTime.Now,
        ProjectType = (short)ProjectType.WebApi,
    }, request.Headers);
```

The code seems OK,but actually the HttpClient is not request the url I give to it!!

Anyone can help, I appreciate it and thanks a lot.

Comment: Could it be that the API you're trying to call is on the same machine? In this case it might be needed to add the URL to your windows HOST file. Otherwise could you please give a little more context to where your API's are running (same machine/different) and what the HttpClient is requesting and what you expect it to request?

Comment: Thank you for comment.They deployed at same machine.But even I run a localhost Web API project to request http://log.api.domain.com. It's still not working.I expect it to request http://log.api.domain.com/errorlog .But actually it request http://localhost:4310/errorlog

Comment: Did you already take a look at your Hosts file? http://www.techfleece.com/2011/08/15/how-to-edit-your-hosts-file-in-windows-7/

Comment: Yes,whether I add the rule or not ,still not working

Comment: It's kinda hard to help you out with this code, where does the URL parameter come from? Could it be that somewhere in the code you get the URL from the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url and that this is not pointing at the URL you expect it to?

Comment: I put this code in the body of a ExceptionFilterAttribute-OnException method. I guess have something to do with this. When I put it in a controller. Everything is OK. I have to give up using HttpClient,but WebRequest instead. And thank you for the patient.